# Minimal bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

If I have a bipartite graph between two sets B and G of size $N$ such that every subset $A$ of vertices in B is connected to at least $|A|$ vertices in G. 
If I delete all the redundant edges (those that can be removed without the condition above failing) how do I know that the new graph is a bijection between the two sets.

Answer (score 1):

By Hall's Marriage Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem there is a matching for every vertex of $B$.

Since you know that you have a matching at the start of the process then find that matching. Deleting all edges not in the matching then doesn't affect the bijection.

A suitable algorithm could be as follows.

Define a subset A of vertices in B to be critical if they are connected to |A| vertices in G. Define an edge to be critical if it is involved in such a connection.

1. If there are no non-critical edges then you have the minimal graph.
2. Otherwise, delete **any** non-critical edge.
3. Return to step 1. (New edges may have become critical after the deletion.)

Comment: Both B and G have to be sets of the same size. I know there will be a matching by Hall’s marriage theorem but I’d like to prove that I’m able to keep deleting edges (providing condition still satisfied) and obtain a graph that gives the bijection. I don’t know how to do this. Would you have a tip?

Comment: Since you know that you have a matching at the start of the process then find that matching. Deleting all edges not in the matching then doesn't affect the bijection.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t clear. I’m trying to prove that there’s a matching by finding an algorithm that decides whether to delete an edge or not. The graph after deleting as many edges as possible - the minimal graph - apparently gives the bijection we need. I’m just finding it very hard to formulate this as a proof and was looking here for any inspiration.

Comment: I've added an algorithm - is that the type of thing you needed.